# php background process PID problem

Tags: php, exec

I have this script and if I run it I get a different PID number entered in the database from the one that is listed with the top command:

```
<?php
error_reporting(0);

include_once "config/mysql.php";

// the path
$path = "PATH=$PATH:/share/MD0_DATA/.qpkg/Optware/bin:";

//random number for the log file name
$random = rand(1,500000);

//initial download location
$init_loc="/share/MD0_DATA/Qdownload/plowshare";

$items = rtrim($_POST['items'],",");
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT url, pid FROM plow WHERE id IN ($items)") or die ('Error: ' . mysql_error());

while ($db_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)) { 
  //random number for the log file name
  $random = rand(1,500000);
  //log file name
  $out_file = '/share/MD0_DATA/Qdownload/plowshare/Logs/log'.$random.'.txt';
  //command 1
  $command = exec("($path" . " nohup /opt/bin/plowdown -o '$init_loc' " . "'".$db_row['url']."' 2> " . "'$out_file' > /dev/null &);" . "echo $$;", $out); 
  exec($command, $out);
  $query = mysql_query("UPDATE plow SET state = 'Active', pid = '$out[0]' WHERE id IN ($items)") or die ('Error: ' . mysql_error());
 }
mysql_close();

?>
```

The result is always the same:

Pid number entered in the database : 11159 (random number, choosen now just to make a point)

Pid number listed with the top commnand: 11161.

The PID number listed with the top command is always bigger then the one from the database by 2.

It drives me crazy ...

Thanks,

Cristian.

Comment: What is in `top` (or `ps aux`) for `11159`?  By any chance is it `nohup`?

Comment: Ran the function again, I got this result: 7696 httpdusr 1856 S /opt/bin/bash /opt/bin/plowdown using top, in the database was entered 7694 ... ???

Comment: But what is `7694`?  My guess is that the PID you're getting returned is `nohup`'s pid.  But `nohup` spans the command as a new process on its own tty, so the pid should be different than `nohup`'s...

Comment: @ircmaxell if you have access to a Linux machine, try to run this command nohup "some command" 2> output.txt > /dev/null & , the number you see at the end should be the PID number for nohup and check with the top command to see what PID number that command has. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

`$$` returns the PID of the script that runs a command, **not the PID of the last executed command**. Per example, echoing `$$` in a bash shell typically returns the PID of bash itself. Echoing `$$` from a script returns the PID of the script.

So, the reason why you get a +2 difference is because:

- exec() spawns a "shell" with PID 1
- nohup is executed with PID 2
- /usr/bin/plowdown is executed with PID 3
- echo $$ returns the PID of the shell, which is 1

Comment: but if I apply the same logic and run the command through Putty, I should get the PID of nohup and plowdown's PID should be nohup_PID+1. but if I run the top command in that list I can see that plowdown has the same PID as the one outputted by the command I just ran. Very intriguing ... Thanks.

Comment: I ran the $command without nohup and the same thing happend, there is a +2 difference between the PID stored in the database and the the one listed with top. ??!

Answer (score 1):

Like netcoder says, you can't use $$, but rather $! which returns the pid of the last backgrounded process. Try something like this

```
$command = exec("($path" . " nohup /opt/bin/plowdown -o '$init_loc' " . "'".$db_row['url']."' 2> " . "'$out_file' > /dev/null ) & " . 'echo ${!};', $out);
```

Notice `&` outside the parenthesis and no semi-colon after.

Comment: Same thing if I try your code, the difference is still there. I need to see if I try it on another machine the same rule applies, I can just add 2 to the value and input it in to the database if this proves to be a "constant". Thanks.